# cygwin: no header file found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header

The following problem: Cygwin or Visual Studio give the error.

```
 CGAL/Splitters.h: No such file or directory
```

This error appears for every header! The header is implemented by the code

```
#include <CGAL/Splitters.h>
```

The error disappears, if I change the code, such that I write the whole path:

```
#include <c:/path1/path2/CGAL/Splitters.h>
```

But this is no solution which satisfies me, because I would have to change hundreds of such code fractions.
I think it should be a problem of Visual studio or cygwin. In cygwin I wrote the command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example
```

What is the reason for the error? How can I fix it?
Please give easy understandable instructions, since I am a beginner in C++.

Comment: what is your visual studio version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know where to look for the header file
referred to by `#include <CGAL/Splitters.h>` unless you tell it,
because that header file is not located in any of the compiler's
default search directories for header files.

You tell the compiler where to look by passing it an `-I` option:

```
$ g++ -I/path/to/cgal/headers -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example
```

where that header file will be:

```
/path/to/cgal/headers/CGAL/Splitters.h
```

Further reading: [An Introduction to GCC - for the GNU compilers gcc and g++](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_9.html)

**Later**

> So for every of the header files I have to write the - I option?

No. `-I/path/to/cgal/headers/` by itself will of course tell the compiler
where to find *every* CGAL header file used in your program.

Comment: So for every of the header files I have to write the - I option? This is a lot of work! Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @DanielBernoulli: No, not for every header file. Maybe for every library though. The easier way is to install them properly into the system's default include path. Read the documentation for this "CGAL".

Answer (score 1):

You can check include path in **Visual Studio** :

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories > Include files

So, check default header file path.

I hope this can help you.